# JQuery popup appearing under some map elements

Tags: jquery, dialog, popup, openlayers, z-order

Pretty new to both JQuery and OpenLayers. Everything was going swimmingly until I've tried to open a modal dialog using JQuery's dialog class.

The dialog works fine except it appears under certain elements of the map:

[image]

This is the same in both Opera and Chrome (Not tested others). Can anyone suggest a way to fix this? Thanks.

EDIT: I've created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GRVuZ/) that demos the problem.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <div id="popup" title="Test">
        <p>Blah blah</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var map;

$(function () {

    //init map
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {});
    var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google('Google Map Layer', { type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID });

    map.addLayer(wms);

    if (!map.getCenter()) {
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    }

    //init popup
    $("#popup").dialog({
        height: 400,
        width: 300,
        modal: true
    });
});​
```

Comment: increase the z-index of popup

Comment: Can you add a link or code here?  Best blind guess is z-indexes and nested elements

Comment: Have created a fiddle, see question, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it looks like if you add `position:relative;` to the map it works as expected.

```
#map { position:relative; width:200px; height:200px; }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GRVuZ/10/)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! Can you explain why this works? Does relative somehow reset the z-order?

Comment: the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371306/html-z-index-and-positioning explains a little, basically that z-index only works on positioned elements.

Comment: more on the z-index http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the `z-index` for your elements.  Here is a fiddle of it mostly working (you just need to find the class or ID for the 'Terms of use' link and add that to the first line below): http://jsfiddle.net/GRVuZ/5/

```
.gmnoprint, .zolControlZoom, .olControlNoSelect {z-index:900 !important;}
#jpopup {z-index:1000;}
```